# How to get children skus list from configurable product?

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4, items, child

I know to load children skus with loading parent object but I am finding the way where I can load all children items by just passing configurable product id, is there any method please share here
thank you
it works fine with below method but it requires to load parent object

```
$configurableProduct=$this->productRepository->getById($parentId);
//\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable
$options = $this->configurable->getConfigurableOptions($configurableProduct);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try following code**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($parentId);

$_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
$getChildSku = array();
foreach ($_children as $child){    
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($child->getID());
    $getChildSku[] = $product->getSku();
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($getChildSku);
echo "</pre>";
```

Manage `objectManager` yourself

Comment: you don't need the `load` in the foreach loop. you can just call `$child->getSku()`. It's faster

Comment: Yes, We can get sku without load. Thanks @Marius

Comment: @MPRaj I already mentioned I do NOT want to load parent object, I need to get child skus without load parent object

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you

```
public function __construct(     
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
) {
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
}

public function getLoadProduct()
{
    // $product_id=7; // configurable product id
    // $configProduct=$this->_productloader->create()->load($product_id);
    $configProduct = 'your config product object'; // your config product object
    $_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);

    foreach ($_children as $child) {
        echo "Child Product Skus ".$child->getSku()".<br />;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but please read question